# File browsing application in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm building an application in vc++. Here I want to browse my file system and select some file. Can anybody tell me how to do? Thank you.

Comment: Are you compiling with the `/clr` option (C++/CLI)? Is using the built-in Windows File Open dialog an acceptable option to you?

Answer (score 1):

FindFirstFile & FindNextFile windows APIs are your friends.